# How to check if user is trying to access script manually with no data sent to the server?

Tags: php

Assuming I have a script named **test.php** I was wondering how I could check if the user is trying to access **example.com/test.php** manually and if so throw a forbidden error `var_dump(http_response_code(403));` Here is my code:

```
if($conditions)
     var_dump(http_response_code(403));
```

Here is what I want $conditions to be:

- User not logged in
- User has no "interest" in accessing that script manually. This is, I want to check if there is a $_POST or $_GET and if there is none then throw the forbidden error

**$conditions = $NOT_LOGGED || ( !isset($_POST) && !isset($_GET) )**

The problem is, AFAIK, the user simply visiting **example.com/test.php** is a $_GET... so this code will fail. What I'd like is a foulproof method to assure the user really is trying to go at it manually (and yes, I'm completely aware the user can do this manually such as `example.com/test.php?but_thats=not_my_point`. Could someone help me please? tyvm!

Comment: How should the script be accessed? It sounds like it is the action of a form submission or something - can you clarify?

Comment: How do you differentiate "intention"?! You can't. What are the criteria that must be fulfilled for this file to be accessed? You've told us a lot about what you're trying to prevent (blacklist); try to tell us something about what you *want* instead (whitelist).

Comment: @Darragh via form, $_POST or $_GET, but that information is irrelevant... the point I'm bringing is that I want the user to be forbidden of accessing the script with no $_POST or $_GET data, as simple as that

Comment: @deceze as told above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple: check all the conditions that must be *fulfilled* for the request to be valid, and fail on each one if it doesn't comply.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'GET') {
    header('HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed');
    exit();
}

if (/* user is not logged in */) {   // fill in your user authentication here
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit();
}

if (!isset($_GET['foo'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    exit();
}

echo 'Hi! ', $_GET['foo'];
```